# What is the correct syntax to call a stored procedured from within a stored procedure using a condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I'm making a mess of the condition statement while calling a stored procedure from within a stored procedure.  Can anyone help me out?

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Leaderboard] 

    @CompetitionId INTEGER

    AS

    DECLARE @Competition TABLE
    (CompId INTEGER,
    CompFormat NVARCHAR(10)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Competition
    SELECT CompetitionId, CompetitionFormatType
    FROM dbo.Competitions 
LEFT JOIN dbo.CompetitionFormat ON dbo.Competitions.CompetitionFormatId = dbo.CompetitionFormat.CompetitionFormatId
    WHERE CompetitionId = @CompetitionId


    CASE WHEN @Competition.CompFormat = "Strokes" THEN EXEC [dbo].[sp_Strokes] ELSE EXEC [dbo].[sp_Stableford]
```

In addition something I know I have not catered for in my code is that I need to also take the parameter @CompetitionId into which ever procedure I go to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use an `IF` statement?

```
IF (SELECT TOP 1 CompFormat FROM @Competition) = 'Strokes'
   BEGIN
       EXEC [dbo].[sp_Strokes] @CompetitionId 
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
       EXEC [dbo].[sp_Stableford] @CompetitionId 
   END
```

Comment: Yeah, in theory that looks good, but I get the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Competition".  Do I need to declare it a second time?

Comment: @gallie: Do you need to execute the procedure for each row inserted into the `@Competition` table?

Comment: @Cory: There will only be one row returned.

Comment: @gallie: If there will only be one row, try it as in my edited answer above

Comment: Thanks for that, no errors now Brian, but not quite there yet as the 2 stored procedures sp_Strokes and sp_Stableford are both looking for the CompetitionId parameter to be passed in.  How do I pass in the parameter?  Any ideas?

Comment: @gallie: Just add the parameter at the end of the EXEC statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want and eliminate the table variable at the same time. Try this:

```
DECLARE @CompFormat varchar(50)

SELECT @CompFormat = CompetitionFormatType
FROM dbo.Competitions 
LEFT JOIN dbo.CompetitionFormat 
    ON dbo.Competitions.CompetitionFormatId = dbo.CompetitionFormat.CompetitionFormatId
WHERE CompetitionId = @CompetitionId

IF @CompFormat = 'Strokes'
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_Strokes] @CompetitionId
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_Stableford] @CompetitionId
END
```

Or perhaps you should create a new stored procedure that takes the `@Competition.CompFormat` as a parameter, and then inside it, use an IF-statement to decide from which table to query.

Comment: I think you need to make the double quotes into single quotes.  Besides that, this looks pretty good.